# PHP MySQL - selecting values from table 1 which are not in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This may be simple to solve but I'm having trouble with this piece of code - I'm a self taught newbie with PHP, and the code I've come up with doesn't seem to want to work.

The pages are for an online entry system for a sports competition. Judges' details are stored in table "club_judges", and users can enter them into a competition by copying them into "competition_judges". This is done via a checkbox form in a table.

I want to add functionality whereby judges who are already added to the competition do not appear in the import form, however my code does not seem to work. I am using a unique field of "bg_number" (the sport's identification number) to search for an existing entry.

Current code:

```
$existing_judges = mysql_query("SELECT bg_number FROM competition_judges WHERE competition='Test Competition'");
$existing_judges_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($existing_judges);
$existing_judges_array = "('" . implode( "', '", $existing_judges_fetch ) . "');" ; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM club_judges WHERE (`club`='Test Club') AND (`bg_number` NOT IN '$existing_judges_array') ORDER BY name ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Error displayed:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''('1234567', '1234567');') ORDER BY name' at line 1
```

For reference 1234567 is the bg_number for my test judge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont u use just one query

```
SELECT * 
FROM club_judges 
WHERE `club`='Test Club' 
AND `bg_number`
NOT IN (SELECT bg_number FROM competition_judges WHERE competition='Test Competition')
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Such a simple answer - thank you so much! It has worked brilliantly, I thought there would be an easier way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a single query instead like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `club_judges` WHERE `club`='Test Club' 
          AND 
          `bg_number` NOT IN 
              (SELECT `bg_number` FROM `competition_judges` WHERE `competition`='Test Competition')
           ORDER BY `name` ";
$existing_judges_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($existing_judges);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I ended up using the result as given above almost identical to this - thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

here's a `JOIN` version

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    club_judges a
        LEFT JOIN competition_judges b
            ON  a.bg_number = b.bg_number AND
                b.competition='Test Competition'
WHERE   b.bg_number IS NULL AND
        a.club = 'Test Club'
ORDER   BY a.name
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: in you are concern about performance issues between `JOIN` vs `IN`, see here http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/